# How to add a Microsoft Certification to Developer Story?

Tags: support, developer-story

I want to add a Microsoft Certification to my Developer Story.

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't bother; it's useless :P

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your Developer Story, scroll down past your profile information (name, communities, etc) to the part where the time line begins.

From the "Add a New Item" box, you want to click "Certification"

[image: New Certification]

Fill out the form that appears, and press "Save"

[image: Certification Information]

When you press "Save", the new item will be added to your timeline

[image: Certification in timeline]